# How to change chrome browser language in selenium automation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, localization, selenium-chromedriver

I want to automate localization functions of a web application. According to my application when the browser language changes, application language should change automatically according to the browser language. How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the language code in chrome options before launching the the driver as shown below.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","<PATH>/chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions chromeoptions = new ChromeOptions();
// for japanese language
chromeoptions.addArguments("–lang= ja");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeoptions);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

For language codes : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50442811/is-it-possible-change-browser-language-in-firefox-using-selenium/50442825#50442825 for firefox browser change