# Is it possible change browser language in firefox using selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to launch firefox browser in a given language in selenium automation. Can I do that? If so, please share some sample code implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the language code in fire fox profile preference before launch the the driver as shown below.

```
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
//For japenese language
ffprofile.setPreference("intl.accept_languages","ja");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

For language codes : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Comment: Thanks. This is great.

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433931/how-to-change-chrome-browser-language-in-selenium-automation for chrome browser change