# Use english as a browser language in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have difficulty to use english on chrome browser with selenium, have tried below changes but still use local language when trying to perform a search on google.com search page

adding `--lang=en-US` or `--lang=en` both not working, search result from google.com page still use local language

trying to use `prefs` with `chromePrefs.put("intl.accept_languages", "en,en_US")` doesn't work too.

How i can force chrome to use english when i perform search on google.com search page using selenium webdriver java binding?

I have read [How to change chrome browser language in selenium automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433931/how-to-change-chrome-browser-language-in-selenium-automation) and not working for me

Comment: Can you share that particular google URL.

Comment: Try `--lang=en-GB` instead

Comment: @cruisepandey google URL: `https://www.google.com/`. Using `--lang=en-GB` seems do the trick. Thanks @Fenio. How do I know accepted value for `--lang` for chrome driver?

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52098821/selenium-webdriver-set-preferred-browser-language-de

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: @J.Doem try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150118/trouble-modifying-the-language-option-in-selenium-python-bindings/55254431#55254431